# php , mysqli fetch data from table using button

Tags: php, mysql

I stuck at point... How to fetch a data from single row diplayed in table format?

Here is my code:

```
$raw = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl");
$allresults = mysql_fetch_array($raw);

while($raw  = mysql_fetch_assoc($allresults)){
     echo $row['your field name here'];
     echo "input type="submit" value="view"";
}
```

I have to fetch data of particular field using button provided next to row variable.

Comment: why are you using while loop? if you have single row

Comment: I guess `$row` should be `$raw`, or the opposit ... At least they should be the same :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysql = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "DatabaseName");
$raw = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM tbl");
while($someVariable = $raw->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "$someVariable[field]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call both mysql_fetch_array() and mysql_fetch_assoc() functions.

Try something like this:

```
$allResults = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl");
while($row  = mysql_fetch_assoc($allResults)){
     echo $row['your field name here'];
}
```

This should work!